# JssorObject is not defined

Tags: jssor

After successfully running this gorgeous slider for some month now, it suddenly stopped working and I receive the following message in Firebug:

ReferenceError: $JssorObject$ is not defined
jssor.slider.js
Line 2635

What could be the reason for this???

Where is $JssorObject$ defined?

Comment: It's in jssor.js (formerly known as jssor.core.js + jssor.utils.js).

Answer (score 4):

To develop jssor slider,

for old version, you'd include jssor.core.js and jssor.utils.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
```

And for new version, you need jssor.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
```

Comment: THX for the answer, this was the problem

Comment: I have now successfully running the new version.

But:

seems to me, that the image-transitions were much smoother in the old version, than with the new version....

With the old version, they smoothly ran from beginning to end.

In the new version, you see short stops during the transition...

Sometimes the transitions even stop halfways, and the new image is shown immediately.

So I have reverted back to the old version...

Is that only happening for me???

Comment: What's your device/os/browser/version? Does it happen with slideshow transition or caption transition? Thanks a in advance!

Comment: This morning the problem is not visible any more....

Looks like good old FireFox had some problem after a hard day's work... :)

Comment: @jssor: Does jssor.slider.mini.js include both jssor.js and jssor.slider.js? jssor documentation includes the mini file, and says, that for development, the others should be used. Might be the cause for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, it does. jssor.js + jssor.slider.js is the source code for debug/development. jssor.slider.mini.js is minimized code of both jssor.js and jssor.slider.js.